# A Cryptic Cryptarithm

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, no-computers, cryptic-clues, alphametic

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #48: Unusual tag mix](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/fortnightly-topic-challenge-48-unusual-tag-mix)</sup>

---

Solve these puzzles to reveal why I made them.

Matriarch mostly prepared oats for American airline location? (8)
AIRLINE + LOCATION = ?
51 7581, 674321 29138 85421'8 141738 (four)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to Stiv for solving the final cryptic clue

You did this to highlight the

> TAGS

Matriarch mostly prepared oats for American airline location? (8)

> The answer is **Sarasota**.
>  The matriarch is [Sarah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Mother_Sarah) from which we remove the last letter (mostly) and add **oats**, anagrammed (prepared)

AIRLINE + LOCATION = ?

> Substituting in SARASOTA for the answer in this alphametic, we arrive at the solution
>  R=0, T=1, N=2, E=3, I=4, A=5, C=6, L=7, S=8, O=9

51 7581, 674321 29138 85421'8 141738 (four)

> Substituting the letters for the digits found in the alphametic, this line reads
>  **AT LAST, CLIENT NOTES SAINT'S TITLES (four)**
>  The answer, as discovered by Stiv, is **TAGS** - with T coming from the last letter of CLIENT, AG being NOTES, SAINT cluing S and "TITLES" being the definition.
>  **Previous answer:** **TEST**, with the T and E coming from the last letters of CLIENT NOTE and SAINT'S TITLES cluing ST.

Comment: Almost there! The final cryptic clue is a standard one (ie. it has a definition in it)

Comment: Do you think the answer could be TAGS? (-clien)T + AG (musical 'notes') + S (an uncommon abbreviation for 'saint'? All meaning 'titles'. Seeing as it was for the unusual tag mix FTC... Possible? @samm82

Comment: @Stiv Yup, you got it! Looking back, I don't know if I would use "notes" to clue any of the letters A-G, especially not multiple at once, and I didn't realize saint = S was uncommon

Comment: @samm82 Perhaps 'uncommon' is the wrong word. Certainly in the UK, 'St.' is the most usual abbreviation in place names and church names, although a quick Google tells me that 'S.' is often used by Roman Catholics, which is a big group of people usage-wise!

Comment: @Stiv Thank you, it had been ages since I looked at this.